# XSLT: creating temporary node in input XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm dealing with XSLT code that handles a *clip* element, which usually contains a *video* element.

```
<clip name="..." ...>
  <video path="..." ..>
     ...
  </video>
</clip>
```

In some cases, the *video* element is not present, which is a problem because it is dealt with a complex *video* handling template. However, the *video* tag, when present, is usually simple and it is easy to retrieve its data. I could then create the simple video element than apply the *video* template on it.

Is it possible to do this using XSLT?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me as with xslt i expect an input xml and a desired output format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a temporary node in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <video>
    <xsl:for-each select="something"/>
      <details/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </video>
</xsl:variable>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can process this directly:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp"/>
```

In 1.0 there is a glitch, which is that the variable holds a result-tree-fragment rather than a node-set. Nearly all XSLT 1.0 processors offer a function exslt:node-set() to convert from one to the other:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp)"/>
```

(But I just re-read the title of your question. You can't actually add this temporary node to the input XML: the input XML is immutable.)